# Great trials have turned on less

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What excactly does it mean when in a sentence "It occured to me then that great trials have turned on less."?

Comment: While I think tunny has given the right answer, it is always helpful in questions like this to give either the source, or at least some context.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the outcomes of great trials have depended most on points less important than the one previously mentioned.  http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/turn-on